# UISearchBar Design glitch on Xcode 11.1

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchbar

UISearchBar design results weird when Build with Xcode 11.1.

I created ViewController and presented from another one. UISearchbar is added below to the UINavigationBar via Storyboard.

**Build With Xcode 11.0:**

[image: Build With Xcode 11.0]

**Build With Xcode 11.1:**

[image: Build With Xcode 11.1]

Why it happened? If this should be the behaviour, how to achieve the first design. How to fix it?

Comment: try this `yoursearchBarName.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white`

Answer (score 1):

As Anbu.Karthik commented, I realised, when compiled in Xcode 11.1, searchTextField's background color to clear color, and we have to set background color explicitly.

**Swift:**

```
searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
```

**Obj-C**

```
self.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```